# Show previously selected dates in jquery's UI MultiDatesPicker plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

I am using multiDatePicker for jQuery UI in a web application I am building. A user can select multiple dates. Their dates are then saved in a mySQL database. How do I show the user their previously selected dates in the calender?

Answer (score 1):

you have to do something like this

```
 var date = new Date();
$('#pre-select-dates').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: [date.setDate(14), date.setDate(19)]
});
```

for full year calender you can use

```
      var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
$('#full-year').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: ['10/18/2013', '02/19/'+y, '01/14/'+y, '11/16/'+y],
    numberOfMonths: [1,1],
    showCurrentAtPos: today.getMonth()
});
```

Comment: Thank you, what would be the best approach if the dates are being stored as MM-DD-YY? Here in order to set the date It would have to be date.setDate(DD) @Gyan Chandra Srivastava